# How do I call an async function in a new process using multiprocessing?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, fastapi

I created a server that wait for webhook signal, and when there is signal, it will create a new process to run the `loop()` function, and when running the `loop()` function, I want it to call the function `printmessage()` asynchronously, so it will run the next line in the loop function without waiting the `printmessage()` function finish processing, but I got the following errors, how I resolve it?

```
#main.py
import time
from fastapi import Request, FastAPI
import multiprocessing as mp
import uvicorn
import asyncio


async def printmessage(fruit):
    print(fruit)
    time.sleep(5) 
    
async def loop(fruit):
    while True:     
        task = asyncio.create_task(printmessage(fruit))          
        time.sleep(1)

fruit="apple"
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("PROGRAM LAUNCH...")
    print("WEBHOOK RECEIVE READY...")   

 
app = FastAPI()    
@app.post("/webhook")
async def webhook(request : Request):       

    print("WEBHOOK RECEIVED")    
    p = mp.Process(target=loop,args=[fruit])
    p.start() 
    print('done')   
    return 'WEBHOOK RECEIVED'
```

The intended output should be printing `apple` every 1 second.

**ERRORS:**

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'loop' was never awaited
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I tried the following way to avoid the errors but there is no output at all:

```
#main.py
import time
from fastapi import Request, FastAPI
import multiprocessing as mp
import uvicorn
import asyncio


async def printmessage(fruit):
    print(fruit)
    time.sleep(5) 
    
async def loop(fruit):
    while True:     
        task = asyncio.create_task(printmessage(fruit))          
        time.sleep(1)

def preloop(fruit):
    asyncio.run(loop(fruit))

fruit="apple"
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("PROGRAM LAUNCH...")
    print("WEBHOOK RECEIVE READY...")  

 
app = FastAPI()    
@app.post("/webhook")
async def webhook(request : Request):       

    print("WEBHOOK RECEIVED")    
    p = mp.Process(target=preloop,args=[fruit])
    p.start() 
    print('done')   
    return 'WEBHOOK RECEIVED'
```

Comment: If you never `await` something, you never give up control; there is nothing async can do to help you here. Async is not threading, so unless your printmessage does an await while it waits for an async print operation to finish, there is no way for other code to run while that happens. Your calls to `time.sleep` will block as they are not async - if you want to give up processing capabilities while sleeping, use `await asyncio.sleep(5)` or similar instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can call an async function in a new process using multiprocessing.
In this code, each request to /webhook creates a new process, which prints *apple* every 5 seconds.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import asyncio
from multiprocessing import Process
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

process_pool: list[Process] = []


async def print_message(fruit):
    print(fruit)


async def loop(fruit):
    while True:
        await print_message(fruit)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


def run_loop(fruit):
    asyncio.run(loop(fruit))


@app.get("/webhook")
async def webhook():
    print("WEBHOOK RECEIVED")
    fruit = "apple"
    process = Process(target=run_loop, args=(fruit,))
    process_pool.append(process)
    process.start()
    print('done')
    return 'WEBHOOK RECEIVED'


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown_event():
    for process in process_pool:
        process.kill()
    for process in process_pool:
        while process.is_alive():
            continue
        process.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("PROGRAM LAUNCH...")
    print("WEBHOOK RECEIVE READY...")
```